# altering the checked property on multiple checkboxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I want to use jQuery to set the `checked` attribute

How can this be done?

```
 var arr = new Array(1, 2, 3);

           <input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="1"/>
           <input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="2"/>
           <input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="3"/>
           <input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="4"/>
           <input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="5"/>
           <input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="6"/>
           <input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="7"/>
```

i want to found arr eq value in checkbox...

```
           <input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="1" checked/>
           <input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="2" checked/>
           <input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="3" checked/>
           <input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="4"/>
           <input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="5"/>
           <input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="6"/>
           <input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="7"/>
```

Comment: hi cherry. do you think you could edit the question to provide a bit more information, such as which box?

Comment: Thank you~
Also solved by people's answers
              var arr =$('#branch_Seqs').val().split(",");
              $.each( chkBarnch, function( index, value ){
       $('[name=chk][value="'+ value +'"]').attr('checked', true ); 
           });

Answer (score 4):

```
for (var count = 0; count < arr.length; count++) {
    $("input[type='checkbox'][value='" + arr[count] + "']").attr("checked", true);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vfXZy/

Comment: @cherry: underneath the score for the answer there is a tick mark. you should select an answer that has helped you the most, using that tick mark, so others know it was most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this which basically reads the array values and checks checkbox with corresponding value.

```
var $input = $("input");
$.each(arr, function(){
   $input.filter("[value='"+this+"']").attr("checked", true);
});
```

In the above code it finds `input` elements only once ans stores in a local variable and in the loop it just filters so that way it doesn't have to find the element everytime.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    $('input[value=' + arr[i] + ']').attr('checked','checked');
}
</script>
```

Comment: Should be `arr[i]`, not `arr[$i]`.

Comment: @Matt Bradley thanks for the edit! That's what happens when you're currently coding in PHP but answering js questions. =p

Comment: :) I'm constantly switching between PHP and JS at work, so I know the feeling. The fact that jQuery uses $ doesn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for (var i in arr)
    $('input[value="' + arr[i] + '"]').prop('checked', true);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZkMsD/

Answer (score 0):

```
var $cbs = $('input:checkbox');
$.each([1,2,3], function(){
    $cbs.filter('[value="'+this+'"]').prop('checked', true);   
})
```

[**JSFiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/JAsM8/)

Answer (score 0):

```
    var check_checkboxes = [1,2,5]; 
    $.each( check_checkboxes, function( index, value ){
        $('input:checkbox[value="'+ value +'"]').attr('checked', true ); 
    });
```

Comment: Cherry, please mark as answered if you are satisfied with the answer, this allows me to earn points and would help me as i am a newbie. Thanks!